# Javascript lambda/anonymous function length warning in eslint or jslint

Tags: javascript, lambda, anonymous-function, jslint, eslint

For javascript, is there an eslint (or even jslint) setting to give a warning for a given length (eg: longer than 5 lines) of anonymous/lambda functions, especially callbacks?

I'm trying to see if there is a way to enforce cleaner code than this using lint:

```
  ...
  var a = foo(b, function(c, cb1) {
    // dozens of lines of code
    cb1(d, function(e, cb2){
      // dozens of lines of code
      cb2(f, function(g, cb3) {
        // dozens of lines of code
        cb3(...);
        // dozens of lines of code
      });
    });
  });
  ...
```

I do know that the number of nested functions can be limited, but I think the length of these could also be as short as possible.

Comment: The [max-depth](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-depth) or [max-nested-callbacks](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-nested-callbacks) rules might be helpful.

Comment: As I mentioned I'm aware of those and using them; I'm looking for something that also limits the length, since it can get unreadable/undebuggable with nesting only 3 deep...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the eslint [max-statements](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-statements) option to enforce a certain number of statements per function.

The max-depth and max-nested-callbacks that Jordan mentioned are useful to prevent nesting conditions and callbacks too deeply. You may also be interested in limiting [complexity](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/complexity), meaning how many different results a function can have.

Comment: I guess there is nothing to limit 'lines' but using max-statements makes more sense than lines anyway; that coupled with the other mentioned options should be enough.